# Listen for 'check status request' (XML)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

Using JavaScript I need to listen for something called a 'check status request'. I'm aware that you don't know what this is, to be honest I'm not sure yet either. I'm being told that the server sending the request will do so every 10 seconds.

I know that the request will be sent in XML format. Is there a way I can use JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX to listen for this request?

Thanks (sorry if vague, this is all the information I have at this stage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about listening.
but you can poll the server and get the value you want out of it.
url: the url where the request is
mdraw: recursive call to continue polling indefinately.

```
function CallThePoll(url) {
    var mrefreshinterval = 10000;
    mdraw = function () {
        Poll(url);
        setTimeout(mdraw, mrefreshinterval);
    }
    mdraw();
}

function Poll(url) {
    $.get(url, {},
            function (result) {
        //do some stuff here
            });
}
```